# How to find nearest frineds MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, geospatial, geo

I have 3 **MongoDb** collections:

- tracks (lat, lon, created_at [datetime], user_id);
- users (user_id, ...);
- users_contacts (user_id, user_contact_id, ...).

I have one user_id.
Need to find latest locations of his contacts (users_contacts), ordered by distanse from his current location (nearest will be at the top of results).
How can I create **MapReduce** functions? Thanks to anyone who can provide a ***C# sample***.

Comment: You should fix the title of this post to help others who search

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at Near/geoNear functionality

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/

something like

```
places.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.GeoSpatial("loc"), IndexOptions.SetGeoSpatialRange(-500, 500));
var query = Query.Near("loc", 50, 50, 5);
var cursor = places.Find(query).SetLimit(20);
foreach (var hit in cursor) {
    // process hit
}
```

Now in your case you would like to query users_contacts

```
  var query =  Query.And(Query.EQ("user_id", "<id>"),Query.Near("loc", x, y, r));
    var cursor = users_contacts.Find(query)
```